# Sencha Touch MVC Best Practices

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

I'm trying to wrap my mind around the MVC framework of Sencha Touch, but I'm finding a couple of different approaches. In one, found [here](http://vimeo.com/17705448), there is an approach to structuring Sencha Touch apps presented at SenchaCon 2010. It has the added weight of being by a Sencha Touch employee, but it is several months old. In other, more recent posts on Sencha Touch MVC, they have tutorials (such as [here](http://www.sencha.com/learn/Tutorial:A_Sencha_Touch_MVC_application_with_PhoneGap), as well as Manning's MEAP *Sencha In Action* by Jay Garcia) that seem to rely on Ext.Dispatch in the views to call specific controller methods, passing additional elements to the controller, which makes the views controller-aware.

My question is, which is considered the best practice to structure a Sench Touch MVC app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest making your controllers view-aware. When a controller receives a dispatch event you should have something similar to the following:

```
this.controllerViewOne = this.controllerViewOne
                         || this.render({
                                 xtype: 'panel',
                                 listeners: {
                                      onMajorUIAction : function(params){
                                           Ext.Dispatch({ 
                                                controller : 'ProperController',
                                                action     : 'ProperAction',
                                                historyUrl : 'ProperHistoryUrl',
                                                params : params
                                           });
                                      }
                                 }
                            });
```

This has the added benefit of having all of the "Main" listeners for each of the controllers views in one space. It also means reusing the views for other controllers becomes easier.

Your views should all have listeners that help abstract the complexities of the individual components and their events / listeners.

I use an UI manager for global UI changes like hiding / showing a main toolbar or displaying a back button.

Comment: So long as you make sure to break your application into multiple controllers this won't cause to much bulking of your controllers.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I agree that making controllers view-aware in that they are listening for events makes a lot of sense. I have also heard that Ext.dispatch() may go away, if Touch follows Ext JS: [link](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?137166-Sencha-Touch-MVC-Best-Practices)

Answer (score 6):

I had similar questions. Sencha automates a lot of getter creation for your view component instances. It's very confusing.

I've taken Sencha Touch 2.0 and put together a complete MVC scaffold application as an example. I've based it off the ExtJS 4.0 MVC architecture. This will work out of the box with the Sencha Touch 2.0 Developer Preview and should save you a tonne of time.

https://github.com/FrancisShanahan/SenchaTouch2MVCHelloworld

To answer your specific question, the latest ExtJS 4.0 MVC architecture sets up listeners to instances of view components within the init event of the controller. Here's an example taken from the github project already linked:

```
Ext.define('HelloWorld.controller.Home', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',   
    views: ['Home', 'SimpleList'],
    .. etc... 
    init: function() {
        // Start listening for events on views
        this.control({
                 // example of listening to *all* button taps
                 'button': { 'tap': function () {
            console.log('Every button says Hello world');
        } 
    ...
```

Let me know if it helps,
regards,
-fs

Comment: Note that this has been deprecated in sencha2-rc2 (Feb 2012). If you declare views in controllers, you get a warning that you should declare all your views in the App file.

Comment: Thanks, widged; I like what I see so far in Sencha 2.